# How can I get Netbeans to use import statements instead of fully qualified class names on autocomplete?

Tags: php, netbeans

I've moved from PDT to Netbeans recently, and there is something I can't figure out. How do I get the IDE to use 'use' statements at the beginning of a file on autocompleting class names?
Like:

```
use \Foo\Bar\Baz;

class Something extends Baz { /* ... */ }
```

Instead, if I use autocompletion I get

```
class Something extends \Foo\Bar\Baz { /* ... */ }
```

I've checked the code completion settings, but the most promising option (smart) wanted me to first write the imports in order to use autocompletion for short class names. PDT was capable writing that line to the beginning of the file.

Comment: It does not, but my laziness would be satisfied if I did not have to write them myself.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In newer versions of Netbeans (i.e. 7.3+), you can press `Ctrl+Shift+I` (`Alt+Shift+I` won't work as expected, though).

First, it searches for any smart or fully qualified instances in your file and then asks you of what types the found ones should be. It then adds fully qualified use statements to the top of your file and changes existing instances in the source to unqualified.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work properly in 8.1. It doesn't seem to work with aliases and puts the imports before the namespace, which isn't acceptable with most coding standards.

Comment: Gave an up-vote because this is good enough but yet another keyboard shortcut to learn. We should be able to configure it to do automatically as suggested by the question.

Answer (score 9):

I use 'Unqualified', then go to the top of the document and type 'use ' and use the autocomplete dropdown to select the class, the fully qualified class is inserted.

The other option is to use 'Fully Qualified' and then copy->paste it in to a new use statement.

I contacted netbeans a while ago about it and they agreed that it would be a good feature, but I never followed it up, should I chase it up with them?

Answer (score 6):

Go to your Netbeans Preferences, then to Editor tab.  In the 'Language' Dropdown, select PHP, then scroll to the bottom.  The last entry is called Type of Code Completion (PHP 5.3 only)  You can choose Smart or Unqualified, and either would most likely solve your issue.  (I'm not sure about previous versions, but I use NetBeans 7.0 which is latest stable)

Comment: the problem is, that neither automaticly adds an "use" statement. Which is the biggest point of this question