# Uses generation in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-7

I wonder is there any way to make Netbeans work like an Eclipse the way you choose class name from autocompletion list and if `use` statement for that class does not exist then Netbeans will generate `use` and will use class name without full namespace?

Let me demonstrate what i mean. We have base image with autocomplete.

[image: Base image]

Current behaviour of Netbeans on when we hit Enter

[image: Current behaviour]

Desired behaviour of Netbeans

[image: Desired behaviour]

Comment: Anyway, the same was already asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016979/how-can-i-get-netbeans-to-use-import-statements-instead-of-fully-qualified-class)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing a short research using Google I have found out, that it could be the **`CTRL`** + **`SHIFT`** + **`I`** key combination to invoke operation similar to Eclipse's `SHIFT` + `O` within Java (*to repair imports*, if I remember it right).

Check the [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/how_to_fix_your_use) where the operation is described.

It should be fine to write down in Your example:

```
$object = new ClassLoader;
```

And then hit `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `I` to import the `ClassLoader`'s namespace as an `use` statement...

Comment: Not the same, but is party solution. Hope Netbeans would work on that.